# jQuery in each requireJs module without requiring it

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I use jQuery with the noConflict(true) mode within requireJS. Now I need to require jQuery each time, I want to use it within my modules. My question is, can I get rid of this? Is there a config saying that the require module should be available in each module by default?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The robust way to get jQuery to be available globally is to load it with a `<script>` tag **before** loading RequireJS.

There is no RequireJS option to do what you want to do. It is possible to do this to start an application:

```
require(["jquery"], function () {
    require(["main"]); // `main` being the main module
});
```

but if you ever have a need to load other modules of the application individually, you have to remember to require `jquery` first. I also consider things like this to actually obscure the code. Someone looking in a module of the application loaded with RequireJS will see jQuery being used but won't see the dependency *in the module's* dependency list. They'll assume that it is not loaded by RequireJS, when in fact it is.